# React.js Error when adding object to state (using react hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function that generates an object that I would like to add to my state. I am using react hooks. Here is my code:

```
const [roomMatches, setRoomMatches] = useState({
                                         "user2":{ "percentMatch":"1.0"},
                                         "user3":{ "percentMatch": ".30"}
                                               })

var newMatch = {
                 survey:{
                            ['percentMatch']: .99
                        }
               }

setRoomMatches([...roomMatches, newMatch]);
```

My problem is that I keep getting the same error

```
Uncaught TypeError: roomMatches is not iterable
```

How can I add to the current state without deleting what is in the state allready?

Comment: Well `roomMatches` is an object, but you're trying to spread it into an array.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're trying to do is merge your `newMatch` into the existing `roomMatches` and then update the state.  To do that, you'd need to do the following:

```
const newState = {...roomMatches, ...newMatch};
setRoomMatches(newState);
```

In the code above, you're attempting to update the state with an array rather than an object (and, as the comment suggests, spreading the object into an array won't work).

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out by Jayce444, you're trying to spread your `roomMatches` object into the array which is not possible.

I believe you want something like this:

```js
const [roomMatches, setRoomMatches] = useState({
  user2: { percentMatch: '1.0' },
  user3: { percentMatch: '.30' },
});

var newMatch = {
  survey: {
    percentMatch: 0.99,
  },
};

setRoomMatches({ ...roomMatches, newMatch });
```

P.S. I'm not sure if it is intentional, but you might want to spread `newMatch` as well when you call `setRoomMatches`.